# Changing the cursor in iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, coding-style, cursor

How can I change the cursor pointer to hand in the iPhone (simulator)?
I tried it with the css `cursor: pointer;` but nothing
happens in the iPhone simulator.  It still remains the default pointer not changing to the 
hand symbol.

Why? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Dude, seriously? There's no cursor on the iPhone? You just tap the screen where you'd like to interact... If you're working in the simulator, it won't change either.

Comment: Did you ever had an iphone in your hand?

Comment: hi i'm working with the simulator.so it appears as the default pointer.

Comment: That's the pointer on your Mac..it has nothing to do with the simulator or the iPhone, or XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a pointer on iOS devices. (Unless you want to use CSS to put gloves on my hands...)

In regards to the simulator, I suspect that CSS support for the cursor attributes would limited if it's there at all, since the simulator is supposed to behave like the device and there is no cursor on iOS.

The cursor which you see is the cursor of your Mac. Pretend that it is on top of the "glass" of the simulator. Safari mobile doesn't know that it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way of changing the cursor but I couldn't find anything. At the end I used Mousecape and added a custom cursor that resembles a finger shadow. I compiled the steps I followed here -> https://medium.com/@castillejoale/changing-mouse-cursor-in-xcode-simulator-72f768f5b434

Hope this helps